# How do I move text to the next item in the collection?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I pass a large text to the collection, but I wrote that the collection element can only contain 5 lines.

```
cell.TEXT2.textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = 5
cell.TEXT2.textContainer.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
```

How can I add new items to the collection and transfer the remaining text to them?

Comment: Firstly please do not do that :). Is it possible to share image or something like that ?.